# how to set a scroll bar size without having content

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid

I am trying to create a data-grid where I am not displaying all the records in the beginning and want to render them when scrolled. Is there a way I can set a scroll size based on the amount of data that I have and change the data in the dev when user scrolls.

I know there are grid's out there but I do not want to use them and want to know what are the different ways to do it.

I have tried looking into the scroll event and I did not find anything about the scroll direction or the current offset. Is there any documentation I can find. or even a technical name to search for would help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can search for a "infinity scroll" with javascript and html.

EXAMPLE HTML: `<ul id='infinite-list'></ul>`
EXAMPLE CSS: `#infinite-list {
  /* We need to limit the height and show a scrollbar */
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;

  /* Optional, only to check that it works with margin/padding */
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* Optional eye candy below: */
li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}`

EXAMPLE JAVASCRIPT: `var listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');

// Add 20 items.
var nextItem = 1;
var loadMore = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
}

// Detect when scrolled to bottom.
listElm.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight) {
    loadMore();
  }
});

// Initially load some items.
loadMore();
`
```

Comment: I do know the infinute scroll and load the remaining records at the end. I want to know how to estimate the amount of scroll for the total number of records. But I actually found something more interesting called Virtual-scroller. Looks like it might fit my needs. Will give a response once I experiment with it.